# VS code highlights jasmine functions in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, jasmine

I've recently migrated to `Angular 6.0`. And `VS Code` highlights all jasmine functions as unknown. It works fine and runs tests successfully. How to let intellisense know about `Jasmine`?

In previous version some workaround worked:

```
import {} from "jasmine"
```

But it doesn't work any more.

Next import in test.ts also generates errors:

```
import 'jasmine';
```

[image]

**Update:** If I add `"jasmine"` to `types` in `tsconfig.json` - it does the trick. But it doesn't work with `tsconfig.spec.json`. I don't need this types in application bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `npm i @types/jasmine` and add `"jasmine"` to the types-array in the `tsconfig.json` file. I had the same issue and this worked for me.

Comment: I already have jasmine in types array in tsconfig.spec.json. And I'm not ready to migrate to the latest version of jasmine. It became much more strict and lead to big changes in 7000 tests